# Laravel 5 validation mimes also checks the content of the file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Does the Laravel validation also checks the content of the file if it's real an image?

I can't find this :(

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'max:1000|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. From the doc

> Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-mimes

If you want to explicitly allow certain types then you can use the `mimetypes` rule instead

https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-mimetypes

Comment: Thanks overreed :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `mimes` for that:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'image' => 'max:1000|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

> Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type..

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-mimes)